# Android ListView doesn't show anything when I run the app

Tags: java, android

I am trying to display a list of products but when I run the app it does display anything on the device.I cant figure out where my problem is.I want to populate the data on my MainActivity.java.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//    ProductsListAdapter productsListAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ListView productlistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.productlistview);
//        productsListAdapter = new ProductsListAdapter()
//        productlistview.setAdapter(productsListAdapter);

    }

    private List<Product> createListofProducts(){
        ArrayList<Product> productArrayList = new ArrayList<Product>();

        productArrayList.add(new Product("Kimbo", 50.0, 0, " "));

        productArrayList.add(new Product("Sugar", 60.0, 0, " "));

        productArrayList.add(new Product("Oil", 70.0, 0, " "));

        productArrayList.add(new Product("Bread", 40.0, 0, " "));

        productArrayList.add(new Product("water", 30.0, 0, " "));

        return productArrayList;
    }
}
```

ProductListAdapater.java

```
public class ProductsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    //reference of activity
    Context context;
    List<Product> productList;

    public ProductsListAdapter(Context context, List<Product> productList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.productList = productList;
    }



    //tells you how many items ARE in a list
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }

    //tells the item that has been clicked at a particular position
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return productList.get(position);
    }

    //tells the position of an item
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list_item,null);
        Product currentproduct = productList.get(position);

        TextView tvProductName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvproductname);
        TextView tvPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvprice);
        TextView btnAddToCart = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonAddToCart);
        //setText only takes string
        tvProductName.setText(currentproduct.name);
        tvPrice.setText(String.valueOf(currentproduct.price));


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: You had never set the adapter ... uncoment the commented lines ... and use right contructor

Comment: don't forget to adapt the listview.

Comment: @Selvin , thank you. I was not sure how set the adapter, cause everything I tried had errors.I didn't know I just had to add  (this, createListofProducts()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like that?

```
ListView productlistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.productlistview);
productsListAdapter = new ProductsListAdapter(this, createListofProducts())
productlistview.setAdapter(productsListAdapter);
```

Comment: thanks @Prexx, i just had to add (this, createListofProducts())